# Error in collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2 with UTF-8 SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, utf-8, sql-server-2012, sap

I'm trying to select a column from my database that has SAP's informations. 
But when I execute my select all my special characters as `'À Ê'` are broken, for example:

```
TELECOMUNICAÃiES (INCLUI ASSIST-NCIA T+CNICA)
```

should be

```
TELECOMUNICAÇÕES (INCLUI ASSISTÊNCIA TÉCNICA)
```

Is there some way to resolve this using a cast or a convert functions?

OBS: All my tables are configured with `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2` as required of SAP, but the columns are `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`

Comment: Assuming SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2 has all the characters you need, you probably have corrupt data.  Cast the data as varbinary and examine the code points you actually have stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the data is corrupted because this collation is default in any Windows